# DateTime format question with negative numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems figuring out why the following code does not work. It returns the right numbers but when it hits -1 the page should stop.

The date fields are date in the mysql database.

```
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pay_posted1)));
$date->modify('+'.$time_frame1.' months');
$NEW_DATE = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$firstp  = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d")); //CURRENT DATE
$secondp = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($NEW_DATE)));

$diffp = $firstp->diff($secondp);

$DIFFp = $diffp->format('%R%a');
$DIFF_p = $diffp->format('%a');

if ($DIFFp == +0) {
    $PAYMENT_ERROR = "<center><h2><b><font color='#FF0000'>PAYMENT DUE 
    TODAY <a href=\"javascript:void(window.open('payment_history.php', 
     '', 
    'width=500,height=600,top=10,left=40,scrollbars=yes'))\">(View) 
    </a> 
    </font></b></h2></center>";
} elseif($DIFFp <= +10) {
    $PAYMENT_ERROR = "<h2><b><font color='#FF0000'>PAYMENT DUE IN 
    $DIFFp DAY(S)</b></font></h2>";
} elseif ($DIFFp <= -1) {     
    $PAYMENT_ERROR = "<br><br><br><br><h1><b><font 
    color='#ff0000'>PAYMENT IS PAST DUE!! <br>
    PLEASE FOLLOW THIS <a 
    href='http://wawoffice.net/contact.php'>LINK</a></font></h1>";
   exit();
} else {
   $PAYMENT_ERROR = "";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish with this code? That will help provide answers guided toward your solution (rather than just figuring out what's not working with your code).

Answer (score 1):

-1 matches the condition `elseif($DIFFp <= +10)` so the last `elseif` will never be reached, you need to reverse the order of the `elseif` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you gramamj42. That was it, have no idea how I missed that.

Comment: Glad I could help. I see you're new here, so please would you help me by accepting my answer and deleting your 'Thank you', which isn't an answer !